# Checkbox not aligned with text

Tags: css, html

Hello does anyone know why my left green checkbox is not aligned on left of the text ? Here is my code and what I see right now.

I want something like this "V Etendre le linge X" for one row (V is the checkbox and X is the destroy button)

[image]

```css
html,
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

button {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 background: none;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 font-family: inherit;
 color: inherit;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 -ms-appearance: none;
 -o-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}

body {
 font: 14px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 background: #eaeaea url('../bower_components/todomvc-common/bg.png');
 color: #4d4d4d;
 width: 550px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -ms-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.sapUiTv, .sapUiBtnS {
 font: inherit;
 font-size: inherit;
}

#todoapp {
 background: #fff;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
 margin: 130px 0 40px 0;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 position: relative;
 border-top-left-radius: 2px;
 border-top-right-radius: 2px;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0 25px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

#todoapp:before {
 content: '';
 border-left: 1px solid #f5d6d6;
 border-right: 1px solid #f5d6d6;
 width: 2px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 40px;
 height: 100%;
}

#todoapp input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 font-style: italic;
}

#todoapp input:-moz-placeholder {
 font-style: italic;
 color: #a9a9a9;
}

#todoapp h1 {
 position: absolute;
 top: -120px;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 70px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 color: #b3b3b3;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
 text-shadow: -1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 -webkit-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
 -moz-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
 -ms-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
 -o-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
 text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

#header {
 padding-top: 15px;
 border-radius: inherit;
}


#main {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 border-top: 1px dotted #adadad;
}

#new-todo,
.sapUiTfBrd.sapUiTfRo.todo,
.sapUiTfBrd.sapUiTfStd.todo {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 margin-right: 153px;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: inherit;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 0;
 outline: none;
 color: #4D4D4D;
 padding: 6px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -ms-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 font-smoothing: antialiased;
}


#new-todo {
 padding: 15px 15px 16px 60px;
 border: none;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
 z-index: 2;
 box-shadow: none;
}

#todo-list {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

#todo-list li {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 24px;
 border-top: 1px dotted #ccc;
}

#todo-list input[type='checkbox'] {
 text-align: center;
 width: 40px;
 /* auto, since non-WebKit browsers doesn't support input styling */
 height: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: auto 0;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 /*-moz-appearance: none;*/
 -ms-appearance: none;
 -o-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}

#todo-list input[type='checkbox']:after {
 content: '✔';
 line-height: 62px;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #d9d9d9;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #bfbfbf;
}

#todo-list input[type='checkbox']:checked:after {
 color: #85ada7;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #669991;
 bottom: 1px;
 position: relative;
}

#todo-list input:not([type='checkbox']) {
 word-break: break-word;
 padding: 15px;
 margin-left: 45px;
 display: block;
 line-height: 1.2em;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.4s;
 -moz-transition: color 0.4s;
 -ms-transition: color 0.4s;
 -o-transition: color 0.4s;
 transition: color 0.4s;
}

#todo-list li .destroy {
 outline: none;
 background-color: transparent;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 10px;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 margin: auto 0;
 font-size: 22px;
 color: #a88a8a;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s;
 transition: all 0.2s;
}

#todo-list li .destroy:hover {
 text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000,
     0 0 10px rgba(199, 107, 107, 0.8);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
 -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
 -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
 -o-transform: scale(1.3);
 transform: scale(1.3);
}

#todo-list li .destroy:after {
 content: '✖';
}

#todo-list li:hover .destroy {
 display: block;
}

#todo-list .sapUiRrNoData,
#todo-list .sapUiRrPtb,
#todo-list .sapUiRrFtr {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
 <title>MyTodoList</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <section id = "todoapp">
  <header id="header">
   <h1>MyTodoList</h1>
   <form action="#" id="todo-form">
    <input type="text" id="new-todo" placeholder="New task" autofocus autocomplete="off">
   </form>
  </header>

 
  <section id = "main">
   <u1 id = "todo-list">
    <li>
     <div class="view">
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
      <label>Etendre le linge</label>
      <button class="destroy"></button>
     </div>
    </li>
   </u1>
  </section>
 </section>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
 libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The amount of CSS you provide is quite scary. You should just provide an unnecessary part and also make use of Stack Snippets, to provide the reproducible demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `position:absolute` on your checkbox. Removing it fixes the issue.

```
#todo-list input[type='checkbox'] {
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    height: auto;
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* top: 0;             */
    /* bottom: 0;          */
    margin: auto 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```